# Import CSS-file from upper directory

Tags: php, html, css

So I just made a new folder called "members" in the folder I have the file edit.php.

To import the PHP-files I need I used this snippet

```
<?php require(''.dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/files/head.php'); ?>
```

And to import CSS-files I used "../"

The problem is that I have some CSS-files that are in my imported PHP-files.
That means I can't use "../" because then it would screw up the CSS for the files above the members folder.

How may I work around this? Should I use some PHP to add it or any other ideas?

Comment: Why dont you put the css' into its own file?

Comment: @rlatief : I think the OP still wants to make it better to maintain.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. We need to see the code on the PHP page that has your CSS files. Looks like you probably have code creating the `<head>`.

Comment: If your problem was clear, then mark the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to this case is only remove "../" in your head.php, then replace it with absolute URL instead of dynamic URL.